# Javascript Creating an image element and drawing it in canvas

Tags: javascript

So I am trying to create an image element and then draw it onto a canvas with Javascript for an assingment. Here is my code

```
function drawCanvas() {
document.getElementById("heading").innerHTML = "Canvas Information";    
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
clearCanvas();
var x = document.createElement("IMG");
x.setAttribute("src", "pudge.png");
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
ctx = c.getContext('2d');
c.width = window.innerWidth;
c.height = window.innerHeight;
ctx.drawImage(x,0,0);
```

My problem is that for some reason, the code won't work on the first try, but after I run it once it will work fine, even if clear the canvas my other functions. I assume it can't create an image and then draw it on the canvas in one go, because if I put the image element straight into html with some id and call it like I did the canvas with getElementById then it works, but I wanted to create the element in the function itself without modifying the HTML. I tried creating a createImage() function with just

```
var x = document.createElement("IMG");
x.setAttribute("src", "pudge.png");
return x;
```

to no avail. Any help?

Edit: Sorry for the lack of code, this was an assignment so I didn't want to put out too much code that someone could find and copy. I was about to post it but someone answered already below with the eventlistener tip, TY guys!

Comment: Please share your complete code, looks like you don't have the closing bracket in your function `drawCanvas`. And you have also left out `clearCanvas`. Feel free to use something like https://repl.it/languages/web_project to help.

Comment: When you call `.createElement()`, you haven't actually inserted it into the page. You need to actually **append** it to the page with `[DomElement].appendChild(x)`;

Comment: @ObsidianAge You don't need to insert the image onto the page if it is rendered on a canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allow the image to load first. Once it loads, you can draw it to the canvas.

Add `addEventListener('load', e => ...)` to your image

```
function drawCanvas() {
  document.getElementById("heading").innerHTML = "Canvas Information";
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
  clearCanvas();
  var x = document.createElement("IMG");
  x.setAttribute("src", "pudge.png");
  x.addEventListener('load', e => {
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    ctx = c.getContext('2d');
    c.width = window.innerWidth;
    c.height = window.innerHeight;
    ctx.drawImage(x, 0, 0);
  })
}
```

**Side note:** Not sure if there is a difference, but you can use `var x = new Image` instead of `document.createElement('img')`

Comment: Thank you so much!! this worked, says I need to wait 5 mins to accept answer so gonna stick around to check it off, this was my first time posting can't believe how fast you guys are!